# Updating model from directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive to drag and drop.

The drag and drop works well, but I have a problem with updating the model.
After I drop some text into textarea, the text is showing ok, but the model is not updating.

What am I missing here?

//markup

```
 <textarea drop-on-me id="editor-texto" ng-trim="false" ng-model="mymodel"
 name="templateSms.template">test.</textarea>
```

//directive

```
angular
  .module('clinang')
  .directive('dragMe', dragMe)
  .directive('dropOnMe', dropOnMe);

dragMe.$inject = [];

function typeInTextarea(el, newText) {
  var start = el.selectionStart
  var end = el.selectionEnd
  var text = el.value
  var before = text.substring(0, start)
  var after  = text.substring(end, text.length)
  el.value = (before + newText + after)
  el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = start + newText.length
  el.focus()
}

function dragMe() {
  var DDO = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.prop('draggable', true);
      element.on('dragstart', function(event) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData('text', event.target.id)
      });
    }
  };
  return DDO;
}
dropOnMe.$inject = [];
function dropOnMe() {
  var DDO = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('dragover', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
      element.on('drop', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        var x=document.getElementById(data);
        typeInTextarea(event.target,x.getAttribute('data-value'))
      });
    }
  };
  return DDO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `textarea` model inside `typeInTextarea` function and using `$apply` run digest cycle to update the model change across whole app. For that with your current structure of directives with only link functions you'll need to pass scope to the `typeInTextarea` function (as a parameter).
So your function will be:

```
function typeInTextarea(scope, el, newText) {
  var start = el.selectionStart
  var end = el.selectionEnd
  var text = el.value
  var before = text.substring(0, start)
  var after  = text.substring(end, text.length)
  el.value = (before + newText + after);
  scope.mymodel.textnote = el.value;
  el.selectionStart = el.selectionEnd = start + newText.length;
  el.focus();
}
```

and dropOnMe function will be:

```
function dropOnMe() {
  var DDO = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on('dragover', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
      element.on('drop', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        var x=document.getElementById(data);
        typeInTextarea(scope, event.target,x.getAttribute('data-value'))
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
  return DDO;
}
```

Check out this example (I don't know which element you're dragging so e.g. I've considered span element & just used innerHTML for that ):

https://plnkr.co/edit/wGCNOfOhoopeZEM2WMd1?p=preview